# What are the Java primitive data type modifiers?

Tags: java, primitive, prefix, primitive-types, modifier

Alright, I've been programming in Java for the better part of three years, now, and consider myself very experienced. However, while looking over the Java SE source code, I ran into something I didn't expect:

in `class` `Double`:

```
public static final double MIN_NORMAL = 0x1.0p-1022; // 2.2250738585072014E-308

public static final double MIN_VALUE = 0x0.0000000000001P-1022; // 4.9e-324
```

I did not expect this and can't find out what it means. If you don't know, I'm referring to the `p` and `P` that are after these numbers, before the subtraction operator. I know you can use suffixes to force a number to be a `double`, `long`, `float`, etc., but I've never encountered a `p` or `P`. I checked [the Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), but it doesn't mention it. **Is there a *complete* list of Java primitive number literal modifiers somewhere? Does anyone know them all?**

For reference, below are the ones I've used or encountered, with the ones whose purposes elude me in bold with question marks (`#` represents any arbitrary number within respective limits):

Suffixes:

- `#` = 32-bit integer `int`
- `#L` = 64-bit integer `long`
- **`#l` = another 64-bit integer `l`?**
- `#f` = 32-bit floating-point `float`
- **`#F` = another 32-bit floating-point `float`?**
- `#d` = 64-bit floating-point `double`
- **`#D` = another 64-bit floating-point `double`?**
- `#e#` = scientific notation
- **`#E#` = another scientific notation?**
- **`#p` = ?**
- **`#P` = ?**
- **Any more?**

Prefixes:

- `0b#` = binary (base 2) literal
- **`0B#` = another binary (base 2) literal?**
- `0#` = octal (base 8) literal
- `#` = decimal (base 10) literal
- `0x#` = hexadecimal (base 16) literal
- **`0X#` = another hexadecimal (base 16) literal?**
- **Any more?**

Other (**are there suffixes or prefixes for these?**):

- `(byte)#` = 8-bit integer `byte`
- `(short)#` = 16-bit integer `short`
- `(char)#` - 32-bit character `char`

Comment: The JLS is your friend. When you find a language element you do not understand, don't go to the tutorial, go to that which specifies the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

P is the exponent. It does not matter if it's capital or not.

According to the [Javadoc for `toHextString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString(double)) (which we know is being used because it begins with `0x`:

> `public static String toHexString(double d)` Returns a hexadecimal string representation of the double argument. All characters mentioned below are ASCII characters. If the argument is NaN, the result is the string "NaN". Otherwise, the result is a string that represents the sign and magnitude of the argument. If the sign is negative, the first character of the result is '-' ('\u002D'); if the sign is positive, no sign character appears in the result. As for the magnitude m:
>
> - If m is infinity, it is represented by the string "Infinity"; thus,    positive infinity produces the result "Infinity" and negative
>   infinity produces the result "-Infinity".
> - If m is zero, it is represented by the string "0x0.0p0"; thus,    negative zero produces the result "-0x0.0p0" and positive zero    produces the result "0x0.0p0".
> - If m is a double value with a normalized representation, substrings    are used to represent the significand and exponent fields. The    significand is represented by the characters "0x1." followed by a  lowercase hexadecimal representation of the rest of the significand    as a fraction. Trailing zeros in the hexadecimal representation are    removed unless all the digits are zero, in which case a single zero    is used. Next, **the exponent is represented by "p" followed by a    decimal string of the unbiased exponent** as if produced by a call to  Integer.toString on the exponent value.
> - If m is a double value with a subnormal representation, the    significand is represented by the characters "0x0." followed by a    hexadecimal representation of the rest of the significand as a    fraction. Trailing zeros in the hexadecimal representation are    removed. Next, the exponent is represented by "p-1022". Note that   there must be at least one nonzero digit in a subnormal significand.

According to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10), the following pieces of grammar are accepted:

`3.10.1. Integer Literals`

> `IntegerTypeSuffix`:
>
> - l
> - L
>
> OctalNumeral:
>
> - 0 OctalDigits
> - 0 Underscores OctalDigits
>
> HexNumeral:
>
> - 0 x HexDigits
> - 0 X HexDigits
>
> BinaryNumeral:
>
> - 0 b BinaryDigits
> - 0 B BinaryDigits

`3.10.2. Floating-Point Literals`

> ExponentIndicator: one of
>
> - e
> - E
>
> FloatTypeSuffix: one of
>
> - f
> - F
> - d
> - D
>
> HexSignificand:
>
> - HexNumeral
> - HexNumeral .
> - 0 x HexDigitsopt . HexDigits
> - 0 X HexDigitsopt . HexDigits
>
> BinaryExponentIndicator: one of
>
> - p
> - P

No other single character literals are specified for those purposes.

Answer (score 3):

All of the legal ways to declare a literal are defined in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).

- `p` or `P` is the binary exponent of a number.
- `l` or `L` defines a `long`.
- `f` or `F` defines a `float`.
- `d` or `D` defines a `double`.
- `0B` or `0b` defines a binary literal.
- `0x` or `0X` defines a hexadecimal literal.
- `e` or `E` is also an exponent, but since `e` is a valid character in hexadecimal, `p` is also used.

Comment: I'd choose this as an answer because it most closely relates to my question, but it's missing `e` and `E`. Are you sure this is a COMPLETE list?

Comment: @Supuhstar I just went through the JLS and marked all instances of suffixes and prefixes.

Comment: @Supuhstar I never claimed this was a complete list. I was responding to the OP's bolded items. Looks like I missed one

Answer (score 0):

`P` or `p` is a `BinaryExponentIndicator`. See the Java language specification.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html#3.10.2